# How to query textarea elements by value using react-testing-library and Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, textarea, react-testing-library

I am working on a text-editing webapp and use react-testing-library and jest for testing. The app has a dynamic number of textareas and in order to test behavior I want to get a reference to a textarea using it's known value, however, I am unable to get this to work using RTL's queries.

I tried both `getByText('known cell content')` and `getByDisplayValue('known cell content')`, and both fail the test with the message that the text could not be found. The text queried for is obviously present in the accompanying DOM printout:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: som impliserer at . This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

 ...
              <textarea
                class="InputCellstyled__InputCellStyled-sc-1qia2ur-0 cntSTH"
              >
                 R'(t) = 240t^2 + 20t^3 - 10t^4 = -10t^2(t-6)(t+4) = 0
              </textarea>
              <textarea
                class="InputCellstyled__InputCellStyled-sc-1qia2ur-0 cntSTH"
              >
                som impliserer at <--- WHY IS THIS NOT FOUND?
              </textarea>
              <textarea
                class="InputCellstyled__InputCellStyled-sc-1qia2ur-0 cntSTH"
              >
                t = -4 \quad , \quad t = 6 \quad \text{ eller } \quad t=0.
              </textarea>
```

My current workaround is this tedious bit of code:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).filter(
      (taEl) => taEl.value === 'known cell content'
    )[0];
```

This works, but I would much rather use RTL. How can I query textarea elements by value using RTL's queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to [query by display value](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bydisplayvalue) ?

Comment: Yep. `queryBy` also doesn't find the element I am looking for, it just doesn't fail the test in doing so. I figured it out, posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured it out immediately after asking the question. For anyone interested, what solved it for me was simply to trim the leading and trailing whitespaces from the text I was querying for:

```js
screen.getByText(cell.value.trim())
```